# Change default magento shipping price

Tags: php, javascript, magento

So this website basically delivers flowers to people and depending on how far away the shipment is, it's going to cost more for the shipping. There are two prices: 12.95 and 30.00. The owner of the website wants it to automatically say "12.95" before a zip code or anything is typed in because he says its "turning people away" to see 30.00 like that. If they type the zip code in, it isn't a problem. It'll display the correct amount. I need it to say 12.95, or be totally blank until a zip code is typed in, by default instead of 30.00. any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**

The zip code input and the radio button to select the price are on 2 different pages. Theyre under 1 larger umbrella page, but it doesnt seem to be able to detect the zip code tag OR the radio button/label. Thats why i cant simply make it invisible until a zip code is typed. because i can't bridge javascript across two pages like that.

**EDIT 2**

well im not sure how all 3 pages come together, but im assuming that the zip code page and the radio button page are "included". they arent part of the actual document, so they cant be accessed via the DOM. when theyre displayed on the page, all the code comes together as a whole. or it appears that way. so i tried to manipulate the variables via the dom but it couldnt find them. then i tried to change things via cookies but that gave me a world of shit too. didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Set the price to 12.95 and set an onChange eventListener to the zip code input that will recalculate the price.

```
$('#zipCode').change(function() {
  updatePrice($(this).val());
});
```

It's hard to give specifics without actual code, sorry.

Comment: 2 different pages. cant bridge the JS across 2 pages to recognize both variables

Comment: I'm confused how you can't access something via the DOM.  Can you not modify the 'umbrella' page?  I think you'll need to make an AJAX method to handle this (since I'm assuming you can't also do a page refresh).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was document ready, in jQuery. That's why I couldn't modify the code from the umbrella page; the page wasnt completely loading by the time my scripts were being executed. Here's the code I used:

```
<script>
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j( document ).ready(function() {
        if (document.getElementById("shipping:postcode").value != "") {
            document.getElementById("labelbutton_super").style.display='block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("labelbutton_super").style.display='none';
        }
    });
</script>
```